# Need a stable IP to ssh from

Tags: ssh, remote-access, static-ip

This is probably a dumb question as I am a developer rather that a sysadmin, but here is my situation:

I have a client for whom I created a site hosted on a server in the cloud. I configured hosts.deny to deny all and hosts.allow to accept only connections from my home and a server at work.

My fear is that I could someday become locked out of this server as my home IP changes occasionally.

**Is there any (super cheap) kind of service that would allow me to ssh into the server from a known IP in the case that I became locked out of the server?**

I've considered a micro-instance at ec2, but the cost over time is not trivial. Any other clever suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: dyn-dns and similar could give you what you need, but configuring public-key access only + fail2ban should be good enough

Comment: Another solution is to have a CGI script on a web page that is password protected, and which when you connect and authenticate to it will store your ip address in a file. Then have another script that will look in that file and add the address in it to hosts.allow. Do a web search for "ssh web knocking" for implementations.

Comment: When you get locked out, fire up an EC2 micro instance (which'll have a fresh IP) and use that to log in and unblock your personal IP. Easy and it'll cost you $0.02 if you can do it in less than an hour. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> I have a client for whom I created a site hosted on a server in the cloud. I configured hosts.deny to deny all and hosts.allow to accept only connections from my home and a server at work. My fear is that I could someday become locked out of this server as my home IP changes occasionally.

That you're assuming the solution to this problem is that you need a second server with a static IP to begin with really seems strange. For example, my home server is set up like this:

- [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) makes sure malicious SSH logins are blocked -- the whole Internet is welcome to try but if you fail five times, you are banned forever (or until manually reset)
- non-standard SSH port to avoid the majority of bruteforce bots out there
- user "root" is disabled

For an enterprise solution, I would add the following:

- Set up passwordless key-based authentication (don't lose the key)
- Whitelist the IP-ranges for the ISP or country of you and the server at work, making dynamic IP a non-issue but still keeping anyone else out.

Even if you think this solution is way off, I would suggest you re-think the sanity of getting an entirely separate server just to bypass a badly configured blacklist.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could speak with your isp about getting a static IP, some of them do offer services like that.

Alternatively i think EC2 Elastic ip might be useful: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346

Keep the ip address in EC2 and create a micro instance in case you loose access from home. You will only need to pay for the time the micro instance is up.

EDIT:
Note that the ip address while not in use will cost 0.005 dollars per hour. This is not much however.

Also, this could be used as a complement to 5 try then block setup that bigbadonk420 mentioned. (In case you are clumpsy)

Answer (score 1):

You can use hostnames / domains in your hosts.allow. So using a dyndns provider like dawud mentioned is a good approach.